# how can I write JSNAUGHTY and AUTONYM like the the one in photo?

Tags: fonts

How can I write JSNAUGHTY and AUTONYM like the the one in photo?
[image]

Answer (score 12):

Those are called "small caps", and you can use them with `\textsc{...}` or with the switch `\scshape`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\textsc{JSnaughty} {\scshape Autonym}
\end{document}
```

[image]